No solution found for a simple non-linear simulation using Gekko
Below is my simple code, it is supposed to simulate two tanks feeding into a third tank. The height of the liquid in each tank is the state, and the feed to tank 1 and 2 are the control inputs.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# Parameters
A1 = 1.0   # Cross-sectional area of tank 1
A2 = 1.0   # Cross-sectional area of tank 2
k1 = 0.1   # Coefficient for outflow from tank 1
k2 = 0.1   # Coefficient for outflow from tank 2
k3 = 0.1   # Coefficient for outflow from tank 3
dt = 0.1   # Time step
t_final = 20  # Final time

# Create a Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Time vector
time = np.arange(0, t_final + dt, dt)
m.time = time

# Create variables for heights of the tanks
h1 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0, ub=1)  # Height of tank 1
h2 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0, ub=1)  # Height of tank 2
h3 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0, ub=1)  # Height of tank 3

# Create parameters for input flows
u1 = m.Param(value=1.0)  # Input flow to tank 1
u2 = m.Param(value=1.0)  # Input flow to tank 2


# Define outflows as intermediate variables
out1 = m.Intermediate(k1 * m.sqrt(h1))
out2 = m.Intermediate(k2 * m.sqrt(h2))
out3 = m.Intermediate(k3 * m.sqrt(h3))

# Create the differential equations
m.Equation(h1.dt() == u1 / A1 - out1)
m.Equation(h2.dt() == u2 / A2 - out2)
m.Equation(h3.dt() == out1 + out2 - out3)

# Set the IMODE for dynamic simulation
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 3

# Solve the model
m.solve(disp=True)

# Plotting the results
plt.plot(time, h1.value, label='Height of Tank 1 (h1)', color='blue')
plt.plot(time, h2.value, label='Height of Tank 2 (h2)', color='green')
plt.plot(time, h3.value, label='Height of Tank 3 (h3)', color='orange')
plt.title('Heights of Three Interconnected Tanks Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Height (m)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()`

The error I get trying to run it is:
{
    "name": "Exception",
    "message": "@error: Solution Not Found
",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 45
     42 m.options.SOLVER = 3
     44 # Solve the model
---> 45 m.solve(disp=True)
     47 # Plotting the results
     48 plt.plot(time, h1.value, label='Height of Tank 1 (h1)', color='blue')

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py:2140, in GEKKO.solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   2138         print(\"Error:\", errs)
   2139     if (debug >= 1) and record_error:
-> 2140         raise Exception(apm_error)
   2142 else: #solve on APM server
   2143     def send_if_exists(extension):

Exception: @error: Solution Not Found
"
}

Equivalent simulation using Scipy solve_ivp and casadi has worked, but not Gekko, so what am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to simulate a non-linear system using Gekko and plot the dynamics of the system.

The problem is with the upper bound constraints ub=1.
# Create variables for heights of the tanks
h1 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0, ub=1)  # Height of tank 1
h2 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0, ub=1)  # Height of tank 2
h3 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0, ub=1)  # Height of tank 3

Remove the upper bounds and it solves successfully. There is no feasible solution when those bounds restrict the solution because the tank levels fill higher than the limit of 1.0.
h1 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0)  # Height of tank 1
h2 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0)  # Height of tank 2
h3 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0)  # Height of tank 3


Here is a complete script:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# Parameters
A1 = 1.0   # Cross-sectional area of tank 1
A2 = 1.0   # Cross-sectional area of tank 2
k1 = 0.1   # Coefficient for outflow from tank 1
k2 = 0.1   # Coefficient for outflow from tank 2
k3 = 0.1   # Coefficient for outflow from tank 3
dt = 0.1   # Time step
t_final = 20  # Final time

# Create a Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Time vector
time = np.arange(0, t_final + dt, dt)
m.time = time

# Create variables for heights of the tanks
h1 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0)  # Height of tank 1
h2 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0)  # Height of tank 2
h3 = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0)  # Height of tank 3

# Create parameters for input flows
u1 = m.Param(value=1.0)  # Input flow to tank 1
u2 = m.Param(value=1.0)  # Input flow to tank 2


# Define outflows as intermediate variables
out1 = m.Intermediate(k1 * m.sqrt(h1))
out2 = m.Intermediate(k2 * m.sqrt(h2))
out3 = m.Intermediate(k3 * m.sqrt(h3))

# Create the differential equations
m.Equation(h1.dt() == u1 / A1 - out1)
m.Equation(h2.dt() == u2 / A2 - out2)
m.Equation(h3.dt() == out1 + out2 - out3)

# Set the IMODE for dynamic simulation
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 3

# Solve the model
m.solve(disp=True)

# Plotting the results
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.plot(time, h1.value, 'b-', label='Height of Tank 1 (h1)')
plt.plot(time, h2.value, 'r--', label='Height of Tank 2 (h2)')
plt.plot(time, h3.value, 'g:', label='Height of Tank 3 (h3)')
plt.title('Heights of Three Interconnected Tanks Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Height (m)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(); plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('height.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()


That solved it. But when trying to convert the simulation into an optimization problem I got the same error: No solution found.
All I did was h1 = m.CV(value=0.0, lb=0)  # Height of tank 1
h2 = m.CV(value=0.0, lb=0)  # Height of tank 2
h3 = m.CV(value=0.0, lb=0)  # Height of tank 3
h3.SP = 0.5
h3.STATUS = 1  # Activate MPC control for h3
Create parameters for input flows
m.u1 = m.MV(lb=0)  # Input flow to tank 1
m.u2 = m.MV(lb=0)  # Input flow to tank 2
m.u1.STATUS = 1        # Allow MPC to adjust u1

One other thing to try for optimization is to limit the lower bound to a small number such as 1e-3. sqrt(0) is right at the boundary of not defined and can cause numeric problems. If you are still having problems with the optimization problem, please create a new question on StackOverflow.
